# Pass argparse to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

I'm pretty much a total beginner at Python, so I apologise if this is a really daft question.

I'm trying to set up a small script to start a process, based on what the user enters at the command line. But I'm not entirely sure how to pass my `argsparse` variables to the subprocess command.

The code I have tried is below:

```
import argparse
import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-g', '--gateway')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--matcheng')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args is args.gateway:

    gw = args.gateway
    subprocess.Popen(['gw', gw, '-vi'], shell=True)

if args is args.matcheng:

    me = args.matcheng
    subprocess.Popen(['matchingengine', me, '-vi'], shell=True)
```

Would somebody be able to point me in the right direction?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `if` statements to `if args.gateway` and `if args.matcheng`:

If the two options are exclusive, I think you want this:

```
if args.gateway and args.matcheng:
    print 'error'
elif args.gateway:
    ...
elif args.matcheng:
    ...
```